# Currency doesnt change when item in cart

Tags: cart, currency, multicurrency

I am using multiple currencies on my website and works perfectly until I add an item to the cart. Once i added the cart, the currency is changed, Magento stalls and eventually times out.

I then have to clear the sessions folder and then everything is back to normal.

The currency won't change if there is an item in the cart.

I have disabled many modules but I still cant find the issue! Also increased php memory limit. The issue is somewhere in the database or the coding somewhere!

Please help as i cant expand overseas if this is not resolved!

Comment: I have just setup a total of 3 currencies, US dollars, British pounds and Australian Dollars. I set them up correctly, it only hangs when there is an item in the shopping cart and the currency is changed. if there is no item in the cart and the currencies are changed it works fine. Only does this when something is in the shopping cart :(

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned how you have set up the different currencies ? Is it also happening when you have only one currency. Also you can look what the sessions folder contains.

One of the tutorials how to set up different currencies http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-currency-shop/.

Comment: I have just setup a total of 3 currencies, US dollars, British pounds and Australian Dollars. I set them up correctly, it only hangs when there is an item in the shopping cart and the currency is changed. if there is no item in the cart and the currencies are changed it works fine. Only does this when something is in the shopping cart :(

Comment: This might be helpful [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)